# How to use resizeMode in iOS react native?

Tags: react-native, svg

The question is for version 0.63 of react native.
I know there are bunch of the same question already in SOF, but none of the answers has worked in my case.
I simply wanna add resizeMode to my remote svg images. This works fine in android, but in iOS (I'm testing on simulator iPhone 5s) the property has no effect! No matter what value I give to resizeMode (contain, cover, etc.) or how i give it (as a style, or a prop) it simply ignores it!

```
import Image from 'react-native-remote-svg';
.
.
.
return (
    <View style={{ width: '80%' }}>
      <View style={{ height: 115,borderWidth:1, }}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: imageUrl }}
          style={{
            width: '100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'contain', display: loading ? 'none' : 'flex',
}}
          onLoadEnd={() => { setLoading(false); }}
        />
      </View>
   </View>
  );
```

The result is that the images are not shown completely as if the container is small or something. But I have used resizeMode: contain! So it should fit in anyway! Right?